# Getting the stack trace in a custom error handler in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using a custom error page in Express, as explained [here](http://www.hacksparrow.com/express-js-custom-error-pages-404-and-500.html).

But when I do that, I only see the error *message*. I'd like to get hold of the same information as displayed in the default Express error handler (the stacktrace, etc.), so that I can:

1. Log it to the console (if I could leave the default in place for this, I'd be happy).
2. Display it on the error page, but only for localhost.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a modified version from @generalhenry's answer. You can access the stack trace
in `err.stack` so you can pass it on your '500' view and do some fancy css styles on it.

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
   if (err instanceof NotFound) {
       res.render('errors/404');
   } else {
       res.render('errors/500', {error: err, stack: err.stack});
   }
});

function NotFound() {
   this.name = "NotFound";
   Error.call(this, msg);
   Error.captureStackTrace(this, arguments.callee);
}

// below all route handlers
// If all fails, hit em with the 404
app.all('*', function(req, res){
   throw new NotFound;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the error provided to the middleware

```
  // Handle 500
  app.use(function(error, req, res, next) {
     console.error(error);
     if (ISLOCALHOST()) {
       res.json(error, 500);
     } else {
       res.send('500: Internal Server Error', 500);
     }
  });
```

Comment: That doesn't display the stack trace, just the top-level error message.

Comment: try wrapping it in a `new Error()`  You are likely passing a string into `next()`  you should really do it like `next(new Error("this thing failed");`

Comment: I'm not "throwing" anything -- if I point an action at the wrong view (for example), I normally get the full stack trace. With this, just the top-level message.

Comment: The stack trace isn't from throwing, it's from `new Error()`  try `(function bob () { console.log(new Error('test').stack); })()`

Comment: But I'm not calling new Error().