# Passing in Async functions to Node.js Express.js router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

This seems like a straightforward google, but I can't seem to find the answer...

Can you pass in <strike>ES6</strike> ES7 async functions to the Express router?

Example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', async function(req, res){
  // some await stuff
  res.send('hello world');
});
```

If not, can you point me in the right direction on how to handle this problem ES7 style? Or do I just have to use promises?

Thanks!

Comment: I think express already handles the request in async fashion. When other request comes in, it won't wait until this finishes.

Comment: I have a hunch that async functions should work... but I'd love to documentation to prove me wrong or right.

Comment: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-router` I think this is something you are looking after?

Comment: express routes just accepts a callback function. node supports async functions. so if the callback function of the route happens to be async, node will treat it as such. it works btw i've done it

Answer (score 41, accepted):

May be you didn't found results because `async/await` is an **ES7** not ES6 feature, it is available in node >= 7.6.

Your code will work in node.
I have tested the following code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

async function wait (ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  });
}

app.get('/', async function(req, res){
  console.log('before wait', new Date());
  await wait(5 * 1000);
  console.log('after wait', new Date())
  res.send('hello world');
});

app.listen(3000, err => console.log(err ? "Error listening" : "Listening"))
```

And voila

```
MacJamal:messialltimegoals dev$ node test.js 
Listening undefined
before wait 2017-06-28T22:32:34.829Z
after wait 2017-06-28T22:32:39.852Z
^C
```

Basicaly you got it, you have to `async` a function in order to `await` on a promise inside its code.
This is not supported in node LTS v6, so may be use babel to transpile code.
Hope this helps.

Comment: **WARNING:** If you use *async functions* directly, express will stop handling errors and will not respond with a **500** status code. In fact, if an error occurs, express will not respond at all, and the client will keep waiting until it timeout.

Comment: this is fixed for v5, from docs, "Starting with Express 5, route handlers and middleware that return a Promise will call next(value) automatically when they reject or throw an error."

Comment: Any answer that doesn't consider the exceptional case is not an answer.

Comment: @MichaelBushe everything is an answer and it can help you understand the problem

Answer (score 17):

### Update

Since ExpressJs 5, async functions are supported, and throw errors as expected

> Starting with Express 5, route handlers and middleware that return a Promise will call next(value) automatically when they reject or throw an error
> [source](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

---

## In Express 4 or less, it sort of works, but not really

While it seems to work, it stops handling errors thrown inside the async function, and as a result, if an error is not handled, the server never responds and the client keeps waiting until it timeout.

The correct behavior should be to respond with a **500** status code.

---

## Solutions

### [express-promise-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-promise-router)

```
const router = require('express-promise-router')();

// Use it like a normal router, it will handle async functions
```

### [express-asyncify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-asyncify)

```
const asyncify = require('express-asyncify')
```

### To fix routes set in the `app` object

Replace `var app = express();` with

```
var app = asyncify(express());
```

### To fix routes set in `router` objects

Replace `var router = express.Router();` with

```
var router = asyncify(express.Router());
```

### Note

You only need to apply the `asyncify` function in the objects where you set the routes directly

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-asyncify

Comment: Note that Express 5 will start handling the async errors correctly:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67689269/895245

Comment: Express 5 hasn't been released in years and might not ever be released.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can't do it directly because exceptions are not caught and the function won't return if one is thrown. This article explains how to create a wrapper function to make it work: http://thecodebarbarian.com/using-async-await-with-mocha-express-and-mongoose.html

I haven't tried it but was investigating this recently.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question asked. Exceptions are not the point of question here although if you had explained something about passing async function then it would be great.

Comment: This is very important side effect, it will male express swollo errors and not show them and request will never return causing timeout for client

Answer (score 2):

**Express 5 will automatically handle `async` errors for you**

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html currently says it clearly:

> Starting with Express 5, route handlers and middleware that return a Promise will call next(value) automatically when they reject or throw an error. For example:
>
> ```
> app.get('/user/:id', async function (req, res, next) {
>  var user = await getUserById(req.params.id)
>  res.send(user)
> })
> ```
>
> If getUserById throws an error or rejects, next will be called with either the thrown error or the rejected value. If no rejected value is provided, next will be called with a default Error object provided by the Express router.

We can test that as follows:

```
const assert = require('assert')
const http = require('http')

const express = require('express')

const app = express()
app.get('/error', async (req, res) => {
  throw 'my error'
})

const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
  // Test it.
  function test(path, method, status, body) {
    const options = {
      hostname: 'localhost',
      port: server.address().port,
      path: path,
      method: method,
    }
    http.request(options, res => {
      console.error(res.statusCode);
      assert(res.statusCode === status);
    }).end()
  }
  test('/error', 'GET', 500)
})
```

The terminal output on `express@5.0.0-alpha.8` is the expected:

```
500
Error: my error
    at /home/ciro/test/express5/main.js:10:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ciro/test/node_modules/router/lib/layer.js:102:15)
    at next (/home/ciro/test/node_modules/router/lib/route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/ciro/test/node_modules/router/lib/route.js:109:3)
    at handle (/home/ciro/test/node_modules/router/index.js:515:11)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ciro/test/node_modules/router/lib/layer.js:102:15)
    at /home/ciro/test/node_modules/router/index.js:291:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/ciro/test/node_modules/router/index.js:349:12)
    at next (/home/ciro/test/node_modules/router/index.js:285:10)
    at Function.handle (/home/ciro/test/node_modules/router/index.js:184:3)
```

If you visit it on the browser, you will see an HTML page that says `my error`.

If you run the exact same code on express@4.17.1, you see on the terminal only:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: my error
```

but not the `500` nor `my error`. This is because the request just hangs forever. If you try to open it on the browser, you will see it hang more clearly.

TODO: how to make it show the stack trace as well instead of just `my error`? [Getting the stack trace in a custom error handler in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508572/getting-the-stack-trace-in-a-custom-error-handler-in-express)

**Express 4 solution**

The simplest solution for Express 4 is to just wrap every single route in a `try`/`catch` as follows:

```
app.get('/error', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    throw new Error('my error'
    res.send('never returned')
  } catch(error) {
    next(error);
  }
})
```

which produces the same correct behavior as Express 5.

You can also factor this out further with some of the methods discussed at: [express.js async router and error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55887918/express-js-async-router-and-error-handling)

Tested on Node.js v14.16.0.

Comment: Express 5 hasn't been released in years and might not ever be released.

Comment: @moltenform some still believe: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/4920#issuecomment-1575635801

Answer (score 1):

Use [express-promise-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-router).

```
const express = require('express');
const Router = require('express-promise-router');
const router = new Router();   
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'myusername',
  password: 'mypassword',
  database: 'mydb',
  waitForConnections: true,
  connectionLimit: 10,
  queueLimit: 0
}).promise();

router.get('/some_path', async function(req, res, next) {
  const [rows, ] = await pool.execute(
    'SELECT * ' +
    'FROM mytable ',
    []
  );

  res.json(rows);
});

module.exports = router;
```

(The above is an example of using mysql2's promise interface with `express-promise-router`.)

Answer (score 0):

To handle async requests in express routes use a try catch, which helps you to try for any errors in function and catch them. `try{await stuff} catch{err}`

Answer (score 0):

An other less intrusive option is using [express-async-errors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-errors)

This will patch express to correctly handle async/await.

```
import express from 'express'
import 'express-async-errors'
```