# Why passing in Async functions to Node.js Express.js router?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I try learning node.js and express for developing a web app. Today I have read a post about ["Passing in Async functions to Node.js Express.js router"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44813401/passing-in-async-functions-to-node-js-express-js-router).

This question doesn't fit into my mental model how route handling works.

I was assuming, that in

```
app.Method('path', function);
```

e.q.

```
app.post('/lgn', (req, resp) => {...})
```

the function would be the callback. And I thought, that async functions are the modern way of callbacks.

Why should it be neccessary to define an async callback?

Comment: Async functions are not "the modern way of callbacks." Also, you don't need to use an async callback in the route handler if you are not doing anything asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you image, why it is worthless for me as beginner?

Answer (score 0):

For example if you have some async part of code (some query in database, so you have to wait certain time and then continue the code execution) you will use async/await or chaining promises. Otherwise,as stated, you don't need async inside your callback function.

Comment: Try to research asynchronous javascript before diving into express and node, it will be a lot easier to understand rest of learning path. :)

Comment: Thanks for answering my why. I'll try to understand the linked article better.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YxWMxJONp7E try NetNinja course regarding async js, it might be helpfull :)

Comment: thanks @MilosMarkoni. I will watch it now.  I just read [this](https://medium.com/better-programming/is-javascript-synchronous-or-asynchronous-what-the-hell-is-a-promise-7aa9dd8f3bfb). Sounds as rule callbacks and async /await the same.

Comment: Think of promises and async/await as "tools" to better handle async part of code, Kyle Simpson explaind it deeply but for a start TheNetNinja, MPJ from YouTube will do just fine at the beginning. :)