# This async JavaScript is returning me an empty array. Im not sure if im putting the async and await in the correct places

Tags: javascript

im writing a route to try and return 5 random files with a for loop.. I cant seem to get arr.push(file) to work sync. Any ideas?

```
router.get('/test',  async (req, res) => {
  let amountOfFiles = 5;
  let arr = []
 for( let i =0; i < amountOfFiles; i++){ 
  let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
  await gfs.files.findOne({filename: `${num.toString()}.mp3` }, async (err, file) => {
    if(!file){
      return    res.json({
              err: 'upload'
          })
      }
     // console.log(file)
      arr.push(file)
     
  }) 
} 
//console.log(gfs.files.find())
console.log(arr)
 return res.json(arr)

})
```

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44813401/passing-in-async-functions-to-node-js-express-js-router

Comment: if you do with `promise.all(arr.map()) ` instead of `for and await`. you get better and received final single result array . [Check out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: Where would promise.all go

Comment: instead `for` use `array.map` and wrap with [`promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). After all map async operation finished promise will return the result array to variable .