# How to populate an Array from recursive async api calls

Tags: arrays, asynchronous, populate

How can i populate an array with chunks of results from a recursive async api call?
Now i just get an empty array.
Basically i have to get all data from a paginated API (It gives 20 result per request)
Note: I can see on console the results (all data) correctly.

```js
function getAllData(req, res) {
  let iterated_result = []
  const entity = req.params.entity
  recursive_get(entity, (skip = 0), sapCookies, res)
  async function recursive_get(entity, skip, cookies, res) {
    const result = await getData(entity, skip, cookies)
    if (result['odata.nextLink']) {
      const newSkip = result['odata.nextLink'].split('=')
      recursive_get(entity, newSkip[1], cookies)
    }
    iterated_result.push(result.value)
    console.log(iterated_result.reduce((acc, el) => acc.concat(el), []))
  }
  res.status(200).json(iterated_result.reduce((acc, el) => acc.concat(el), []))
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to add `await` before calling `recursive_get`, declare the function `getAllData` as `async` and finally the caller of this function will receive a `Promise` as a result.

Comment: mmm well the caller of that function (getAllData) is a route of express js (router.get('/getAllData/:entity', getAllData)). How can i achieve this? (recieve a Promise)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing in Async functions to Node.js Express.js router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44813401/passing-in-async-functions-to-node-js-express-js-router)